# How to determine the active WooCommerce Product Variation Image URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I am trying to pass the active product variation to a wordpress widget.

The widget code for displaying the image is currently:

```
$product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
$artwork_url = wp_get_attachment_url($product->get_image_id());
$unit = get_option('woocommerce_dimension_unit');
$height2 = $product->get_height();
$width2 = $product->get_width();
$height = $height2;
$title = get_the_title();
$price = $product->get_price();
$measurements_display = $widget->dimensions == 1 ? 'WxH' : 'HxW';
```

The $artwork_url is what I am having problems with.  When I visit the site, the variation options successfully display the appropriate variation image.  I would like to pass that value onto the widget with the $artwork_url expression.  I've tried pulling thumbnails, feature images, wo-post-images, and am not getting anywhere.

If anyone could offer a suggestion to this, i'd greatly appreciate any advice.

Thanks
Cameron

I've tried defining $variations and $post-image, $variable_product, but can't seem to get the language right.

Answer (score 0):

To get the active variation image URL in the widget, you can try the following code:

```
$product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
$variation_id = isset($_REQUEST['variation_id']) ? $_REQUEST['variation_id'] : '';

if ($variation_id) {
    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
    $artwork_url = wp_get_attachment_url($variation->get_image_id());
} else {
    $artwork_url = wp_get_attachment_url($product->get_image_id());
}

$unit = get_option('woocommerce_dimension_unit');
$height2 = $product->get_height();
$width2 = $product->get_width();
$height = $height2;
$title = get_the_title();
$price = $product->get_price();
$measurements_display = $widget->dimensions == 1 ? 'WxH' : 'HxW';
```

This code first checks if a `variation_id` is present in the request parameters. If it is, it creates a new `WC_Product_Variation` object with that ID and gets the variation's image URL. If not, it gets the parent product's image URL as before.